# SQL Count with Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, count

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
signal_status    signal_count
---------------|---------------
Average        |    10   
Good           |    11  
Very Poor      |     4  
Poor           |     5  
Below Average  |     8  
Excellent      |    13
```

Total devices are 51 which count should be in that way as defined above in signal_count.

What I've achieved is got signal_status (only the first column). Now I want the count as well but unable to get the count on the basis of devices. This is the query I tried to get the first column.

```
select signal_status from (select case 
when signal_info <= 31 and signal_info > 24 then 'Excellent' 
when signal_info <= 24 and signal_info > 19 then 'Good' 
when signal_info <= 19 and signal_info > 14 then 'Average' 
when signal_info <= 14 and signal_info > 9 then 'Below Average' 
when signal_info <= 9 and signal_info > 5 then 'Poor' 
when signal_info <= 5 and signal_info > 0 then 'Very Poor' end 
AS signal_status from data_channel) AS WTH group by signal_status;
```

I tried all possible ways but unable to fetch the desired results.
data_channel table contains following columns:
`sno (PK), device_id, signal_info, datetime`
and i want it to be joined with table_1 to join on device_id.
table_1 contains the following columns:
`device_id (PK), device_name`

What basically I'm trying to do is I want the count for all the devices having signal strength as good average or poor, but what I'm getting is total records from the table not on the basis of recent device signal_info.
Sorry for anything if unclear.

Note: Using SQL Server not MySQL

Comment: i did that but that is returning the total number of rows not returning the data on the basis of device id. Used count with join but getting total number of records from table.

Comment: What do you mean with `recent device signal_info`? Do you have multiple readings for same device and you need to look only at last one of those? If you can write correct requirements down, then usually solution becomes clear also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT signal_status, COUNT(device_id) signal_count 
FROM 
(
    SELECT CASE 
                WHEN signal_info <= 31 and signal_info > 24 THEN 'Excellent' 
                WHEN signal_info <= 24 and signal_info > 19 THEN 'Good' 
                WHEN signal_info <= 19 and signal_info > 14 THEN 'Average' 
                WHEN signal_info <= 14 and signal_info > 9 THEN 'Below Average' 
                WHEN signal_info <= 9 and signal_info > 5 THEN 'Poor' 
                WHEN signal_info <= 5 and signal_info > 0 THEN 'Very Poor' 
            END signal_status
           ,device_id
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY [datetime] DESC) AS [RowID]
    FROM data_channel
) AS WTH
WHERE [RowID] = 1
GROUP BY signal_status
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. Got my desired result :)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there - you're just missing a call to `count` in your select list:

```sql
SELECT   signal_status, 
         COUNT(*) -- Here!
FROM     (SELECT CASE WHEN signal_info <= 31 AND signal_info > 24 THEN 'Excellent' 
                      WHEN signal_info <= 24 AND signal_info > 19 THEN 'Good' 
                      WHEN signal_info <= 19 AND signal_info > 14 THEN 'Average' 
                      WHEN signal_info <= 14 AND signal_info > 9  THEN 'Below Average' 
                      WHEN signal_info <= 9  AND signal_info > 5  THEN 'Poor' 
                      WHEN signal_info <= 5  AND signal_info > 0  THEN 'Very Poor'
                 END  AS signal_status 
          FROM data_channel) AS wth
GROUP BY signal_status;
```

Comment: tried that before but it is returning all the records in the table on the basis of deivce_id.

Comment: @AhmedAnsari I don't understand that sentence. Care to clarify?

Comment: It is returning all records in this way 

`
    Average        |    3257  
    Good             |    1100 
    Very Poor      |     2668  
    Poor              |     24  
    Below Average  |     57  
    Excellent      |    431
`

Comment: Dear @Mureinik signal_count is basically the count of device_id which are currently having that particular signal_state like Good, Poor or Excellent etc.

Comment: Dear @gotqn as mentioned above in comment this query returned me all the records in that particular signal_status state. What i actually want is that signal_count should contain the total number of devices in that state at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
SELECT signal_status, COUNT(DISTINCT device_id) signal_count FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN signal_info <= 31 and signal_info > 24 THEN 'Excellent' 
            WHEN signal_info <= 24 and signal_info > 19 THEN 'Good' 
            WHEN signal_info <= 19 and signal_info > 14 THEN 'Average' 
            WHEN signal_info <= 14 and signal_info > 9 THEN 'Below Average' 
            WHEN signal_info <= 9 and signal_info > 5 THEN 'Poor' 
            WHEN signal_info <= 5 and signal_info > 0 THEN 'Very Poor' 
        END signal_status, device_id 
    FROM data_channel
) AS WTH 
GROUP BY signal_status
```

Comment: it is returning 1 in signal_count

Comment: Please can you post your query result?

Comment: This is what it is returning
`
    Average        |    1  
    Good             |    1  
    Very Poor      |     1  
    Poor              |     1  
    Below Average  |     1  
    Excellent      |    1
`

Comment: Dear @Nayanish signal_count is basically the count of device_id which are currently having that particular signal_state.

Comment: Do you want the count of device_id instead of signal_status?

Comment: i want to the count of device_id (as status count) with signal_status like how many devices are currently in Good signal_status state etc. What I'm getting from query is it is returning me the total records lies in Good signal_status state.

Comment: Almost there now it is returning me the results in this way: ` Average | 15 Good | 28 Very Poor | 1 Poor | 7 Below Average | 11 Excellent | 47 ` how can i get the signal_count to be total in 51 like i have total 51 device in table_1 so the output should be like this ` Average | 11 Good | 9 Very Poor | 10 Poor | 5 Below Average | 5 Excellent | 11 ` like the above it is returning total 51. Did you got my point?

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are correct, look sample data and output. If you have a different requirement, provide sample data.

```
--drop table #data_channel

create table #data_channel
(
sno int identity primary key,
device_id varchar(100), 
signal_info int
)

insert into #data_channel values
('A',24),
('B',14),
('C',24),
('D',31),
('E',1),
('F',13),
('G',20),
('H',12)--,('A',24),('A',24),('A',24),('A',24),('A',24),('A',24),
```

Query

```
select signal_status,Count(*) as signalcount
 from (select case 
when signal_info <= 31 and signal_info > 24 then 'Excellent' 
when signal_info <= 24 and signal_info > 19 then 'Good' 
when signal_info <= 19 and signal_info > 14 then 'Average' 
when signal_info <= 14 and signal_info > 9 then 'Below Average' 
when signal_info <= 9 and signal_info > 5 then 'Poor' 
when signal_info <= 5 and signal_info > 0 then 'Very Poor' end 
AS signal_status from #data_channel) AS WTH group by signal_status;
```

Output

```
signal_status   signalcount
Below Average   3
Excellent   1
Good    3
Very Poor   1
```